# L20n - how to translate custom attribute in htm tag?

Tags: html, localization, translation, l20n

I have following html tag:

```
<input type="text" data-l10n-id="message" data-validation-required-message="My message">
```

In translation file I have:

```
<message placeholder:"Your message">
```

Placeholder attribute works but I don't know how to translate contents of data-validation-required-message attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it works only with standard attributes.

The only solution I can propose is to set the attribute translation manually via JavaScript. Example:

**l20n file**:

```
<validationRequiredMessage "The Message">
```

**JavaScript**:

```
document.l10n.formatValue( "validationRequiredMessage" ).then( ( t ) =>
    document.querySelector( "input" ).dataset.validationRequiredMessage = t
)
```

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I tried. It doesn't work though. I suspect that "-" in the value might create the problem here...

Comment: then maybe with the camel-case notation: `dataValidationRequiredMessage:"My message"`

Comment: I have no control over what the attribute name is, it comes from a 3rd party framework.

Comment: I was meaning to use camelCase notation in the l20n file, but it doesn't seem to work either. Sorry.